# How to keep something on top of the eclipse console in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am wondering how to keep something on top of the console window in eclipse while the user keeps entering values? I am coding in Java

Comment: What do you mean when you say stay on top?

Comment: Like, a gui element the code has displayed? Because that can't really be done without messing with OS level stuff. You should implement a direct interface in your gui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you'd like to keep the console from scrolling while the application is doing it's thing? If that's the case, there is a scroll lock icon at the top-right corner of the console.
[image]